# java method return type with thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

i am using method to get the value. i am getting value successfully but problem is value retun null in mehod see my code:-

```
String authtoken;

public String getAuthTokenForCurrentUser(Activity act,
        final Account account, final String authTokenType) {

    final AccountManager mAccountManager = AccountManager.get(act);
    final AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future = mAccountManager
            .getAuthToken(account, authTokenType, null, act, null, null);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Bundle bnd = future.getResult();

                authtoken = bnd.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);

                Log.e("token in method", authtoken); // getting successfully 
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                showMessage(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }).start();

    return authtoken;
}    

//call here


MyClass iHealthApp = new MyClass();
    String  accessToken = iHealthApp.getAuthTokenForCurrentUser(ClientActivity.this, currentAppUserAccount,AccountGeneral.AUTHTOKEN_TYPE_FULL_ACCESS);
    Log.e("access token","token "+ accessToken);  // this is null here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should either use `Callable` to retrieve the result of the execution(together with `Future`) or you should wait for the thread to finish to retrieve assigned `authtoken`. In your case what happening is: while your thread starts, you method already returns, returning still unassigned value of `authtoken`.